# Two partial fraction identities for $\frac{x^n}{x^m+k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Consider the following expression: $$\frac{x^n}{x^m+k},$$ for non-negative integers $n$ and $m$, $m>n$, and $k\in\mathbb{C}$. For $k=0$ the expression clearly simplifies to $x^{n-m}$. For $|k|>0$ we have the following identity:

$$\frac{x^n}{x^m+k}=\sum_{p=1}^m\frac{c_p^n}{(x-c_p)\prod_{q\neq p}(c_p-c_q)},$$ where the product runs from $q=1$ to $m$ but skips $p$. We define $c_j$ by
$$c_j:=\exp\left[\frac{1}{m}(2\pi \text{i} j+\text{i}\text{Arg}(-k)+\log|k|)\right]. $$ How can we prove the identity?

**Addendum:**

A simpler decomposition is the following, as suggested and proven by achille hui in a comment below: $$\frac{x^n}{x^m+k}=\frac{-1}{mk}\sum_{p=1}^m\frac{c_p^{n+1}}{x-c_p},$$ enjoy!

Comment: The identity you tried to prove/use is more complicated than necessary. A much simpler decomposition is
$$\frac{x^n}{x^m + k} 
= \sum_{p=1}^m \left.\frac{y^n}{(y^m + k)'( x - c_p )}\right|_{y=c_p}
= \sum_{p=1}^m \left.\frac{y^n}{m y^{m-1}( x - c_p )}\right|_{y=c_p}
= -\frac{1}{mk} \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{c_p^{n+1}}{x-c_p}
$$ In any event, $\prod_{q\ne p} (c_p - c_q)$ is $(y^m+k)' = m y^{m-1}$ evaluated at $y = c_p$.

Comment: @achille hui Thanks for a great comment! I was wondering if a simplification was possible and clearly it is! I will add it to the question.

Comment: @achillehui. Nice remark. Just a small correction: the exponent of $c_p$ in the result is $n-m+1$ not $n+1$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom. achille hui has replaced $c_p^m$ with -k.

Comment: @SDIv. Oh... that's true. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remark that the polynomial $X^m+k$ has simple roots.
Let us call the roots $c_j$ for $1\leq j\leq m$. Therefore $x^n/(x^m+k)$ rewrites as a sum of simple elements
$$\frac{x^n}{x^m+k}=\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_j}{x-c_j}.$$
To compute the values of $a_j$, multiply by $(x-c_j)$ and take the limit
$x\to c_j$. The right-hand side goes to $a_j$ as $x$ goes to $c_j$ while the left hand side goes to 
$$\frac{c_j^n}{\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{1\leq p\leq m\\k\neq j}}(c_j-c_p)}.$$
It remains to prove that 
$$c_j=|k|^{1/m}\,\exp\left(j\frac{2\pi \mathrm i}m+\mathrm i\frac{\arg(-k)}m\right).$$
It is clear that the $c_j$'s are distinct since they have distinct arguments.
Take now $c_j^m$ and you find $-k$.

Answer (score 0):

One method for proving the identity is the following and is based on answers given in the following posts: [post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958207/generalized-foxtrot-series-fa-b-sum-k-1-infty-dfrac-1k1-ka/) and [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962855/show-that-ka-sum-m-1b-left-c-ma-prod-n-neq-m-frack-c-nc-m-c-n-r).

1. Note the following: $$\sum_{p=1}^m\frac{c_p^n}{(x-c_p)\prod_{q\neq p}(c_p-c_q)}\\
   = \sum_{p=1}^m\frac{c_p^n\prod_{q\neq p}(x-c_q)}{\prod_{q=1}^m(x-c_q)\prod_{q\neq p}(c_p-c_q)}\\
   = \frac{1}{\prod_{p=1}^m(x-c_p)}\sum_{p=1}^m \left ( c_p^n\prod_{q\neq p}\frac{(x-c_q)}{(c_p-c_q)} \right )$$
2. As shown in post 1, $x^m+k=\prod_{p=1}^m(x-c_p),$ where the set of all $c_j$ are the mth roots of -k.
3. As shown in post 2, $$x^n=\sum_{p=1}^m \left ( c_p^n\prod_{q\neq p}\frac{(x-c_q)}{(c_p-c_q)} \right ) $$
4. Then $$\frac{1}{\prod_{p=1}^m(x-c_p)}\sum_{p=1}^m \left ( c_p^n\prod_{q\neq p}\frac{(x-c_q)}{(c_p-c_q)} \right )=\frac{x^n}{\prod_{p=1}^m(x-c_p)}=\frac{x^n}{x^m+k} \Box. $$