# Evaluating a hard alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to find the following series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k + 1} k^2}{k^3 + 1}$$
I know this converges via the alternating series test since $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{k^2}{k^3 + 1}=0$$ and $\frac{k^2}{k^3 + 1}$ is strictly decreasing.

However, I have 0 clue as to how to evaluate this.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/576250/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bk%20%2B%201%7D%20k%5E2%7D%7Bk%5E3%20%2B%201%7D%24)

Comment: It may help you : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/968lhsjgef